# Deleting with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How do I change this SELECT so it is the criteria used for deleting?

```
SELECT COUNT(empid), empid, status, deptid from tableA 
GROUP BY empid, status, deptid HAVING status is null and deptid = 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to delete?

If simply records with NULL status in deptId 5, using

```
WHERE status is NULL and DeptID = 5
```

Not very clear if you are looking for more than that...

Answer (score 1):

DELETE with GROUP BY may not work, i guess.

You can try the following and please see whether it works.

```
DELETE 
FROM tableA
WHERE status is null AND deptid=5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM tableA 
WHERE status is null AND deptid = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Delete from tableA a, 
(SELECT COUNT(empid) as count, empid, status, deptid from tableA 
    GROUP BY empid, status, deptid HAVING status is null and deptid = 5) as b 
where a.empid = b.empid
and a.status = b.status
and a.deptid = b.deptid
and b.count > 5
```

Would something like that be what you are looking for? It would delete all records that are part of the group with count > 5

Otherwise you are really not deleting values from a group by and can use a simple delete;

```
Delete from tableA 
where status is null 
and deptid = 5
```